# Conditional probability operations

Tags: probability, expectation

Is the following statement true?

$\sum_{j}Pr(a|b=b_j)Pr(b=b_j|c=c^*)=Pr(a|c=c^*)$

I'm using this statement (with a simplification that g takes on a finite number of values) to convince myself that

$E[E(u_i|\mathbf{g_{i-1},...,g_1})|u_{i-1},...,u_1]=E(u_i|u_{i-1},...,u_1)$ where $\bf{g_i}=\bf{x_i}$$u_i$ and $\mathbf{x_i}$ is a k-dimensional vector.

(by the Law of Iterated Expectations)

The nesting of information sets isn't very clear to me here so I've been trying to convince myself of it but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Comment: I'm actually solving a problem involving the Law of Iterated Expectations (with nested conditioning sets). I assumed the statement above was true but I'm having second thoughts on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not, thought it is close to the correct formula $$\sum_j P(a|\{b=b_j\}\cap \{c=c^*\})P(b=b_j|c=c^*)=P(a|c=c^*).$$ To see this, let $B_j$ be the event $b=b_j$, and $C$ be the event $c=c^*$. Then
$$
P(a|C)
=\frac{P(a\cap C)}{P(C)}
=\frac{\sum_j P(a\cap B_j\cap C)}{P(C)}
=\sum_j \frac{P(a\cap B_j\cap C)}{P(B_j\cap C)}\cdot\frac{P(B_j\cap C)}{P(C)}\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\,\,\,\,\,\,=\sum_jP(a|B_j\cap C)\cdot P(B_j|C).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you think that my application/use of the Law of Iterated Expectation is correct though? The nesting of information sets isn't very clear to me...